# jQuery Autocomplete with ajax, can i do a getall?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have successfully bound my jQuery autocomplete with little trouble.  When I type in one or two letters, the ajax query gets me the results and the autocomplete shows the items.  I am now wanting to trigger the option to "show all" with a button.  I know I can use the code

```
myInput.autocomplete("search");
```

to trigger the list when bound to a local datasource.  When I try to do it on something bound to an ajax populated source, it doesn't trigger the search with an empty string.  I wrote the web api to take an optional query string like below:

```
public IEnumerable<Account> GetAccounts(string query = "")
```

Typing in a letter works, remote triggering via a button doesn't for some reason.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the minlength option. It must be zero for empty string. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the minlength option?
It must be zero for empty string. Check the below link for detail.

[api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength)